# create a resizable selectInput window in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, selectinput

I saw a `shiny` app, [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/radiant.html) which uses a resizable `selectInput` but couldn't figure out how it's been developed. I wonder if anybody has any idea?

[image]

Comment: They used a very simple CSS rule: `textarea, select {resize: vertical;overflow: auto;}`

Comment: Can you please explain how I can use it? I am a beginner.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)

css <- "select {resize: vertical; overflow: auto;}"

shinyApp(
  
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
    selectInput(
      "variable", "Variable:", names(mtcars), selectize = FALSE, size = 5L
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
  }
  
)
```